# Polymer conditional attributes

Tags: data-binding, polymer

When trying to define an element with [conditional attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-attributes)

```
<polymer-element name="hover-button" extends="paper-button" hover?="{{hover}}" attributes="hover">
```

I'm running into the following error

```
Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'hover?' is not a valid attribute name.
```

Still at Polymer 0.5.
Here is the full code:

```
<polymer-element name="hover-button" extends="paper-button" hover?="{{hover}}">
<template>
    <shadow></shadow>
</template>

<script>
    (function(){
        Polymer('hover-button', {
            ready: function(){
                this.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ this.hover = true; }.bind(this));
                this.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){ this.hover = false; }.bind(this));
            },
            activeChanged: function(){ /* foo */ },
            hoverChanged: function(){ /* bar */ }
        });
    })();
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use data-binding features on `<polymer-element>` itself. Furthermore, any attribute that is declared on `<polymer-element>` (which is not part of the attributes `attribute` is added to instances of the element by default. I suspect that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: I tried declaring `hover` as a published attribute but the error is still showing. Is there a way to do this declaratively?